# AccessDenied Exception on AppPool properties, cannot call ApplPool.Recycle() - C#

Tags: c#, application-pool, access-denied, recycle

Running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, with IIS 8.5.9600

In `C#`, after setting up a site, I'm retrieving the DefaultAppPool from the site.

Upon retrieval of the pool,  the following properties have exceptions on them:

**appPool.State:**

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

**appPool.WorkerProcesses**

```
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostElement.get_Collection()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetCollection(String collectionName, Type collectionType)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool.get_WorkerProcesses()
```

So I cannot call

```
AppPool.Recycle()
```

It throws this exception:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostMethodInstance.Execute()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationMethodInstance.Execute()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.ExecuteMethod(String methodName)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool.Stop()
at EBI.Core.Common.WebHelper.IISHelper.AddApplicationIis7(String serverName, String applicationPool, String siteName, String applicationPath, String virtualDirectoryPath, String physicalPath, String defaultPage, Int32 deploymentType, String siteUrl)
```

Online research says to add high privileges to this folder:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
```

So I have increasingly added the following:

- SYSTEM
- Administrators
- IIS_IUSRS
- INTERACTIVE
- NETWORK
- SERVICE
- DefaultAppPool
- NETWORK SERVICE
- CREATOR OWNER
- IUSR

BUT STILL SAME ERRORS.

It's probably a bad idea to add all those rights to that folder, so perhaps there is something else I might be missing, but I cannot find what it is. Any ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where is your c# code deployed?  In a service?

Comment: No, code is just a console app. But in the specific case, I am running in debug mode in Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried starting Visual Studio as an administrator (i.e. RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR) and then attempting your debug session?

Comment: Thought I was, anyway will try on Monday. Thanks.

Comment: in case it's useful... if the w3svc service is stopped, you get the same error message. My .net core app works just fine if i run dotnet as admin, or vstudio as admin. zero issues. Didn't have to touch registry, folder permissions, nothing. I think I can finally say, without great disdain for the cliche, "is it plugged in"?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are trying to access the app-pool from any console application or windows service? If so then the console application or windows service should be executed with a username which has admin rights on the server. The username should also be part of IIS_WPG group. May be I have got your question totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If using c# code and deploying to IIS Server then running AppPool.Recycle() can generate 'Access is denied' error.

Visit the application pool you are running the c# code under, and go to advanced Settings -> Identity and change the Identity to 'Administrator' or some user with Admin rights.